# Problema con panel y formulario Bootstrap

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

Al colocar unas pestañas en el `panel-title`, el formulario que tengo en el `panel-primary` llega hasta el límite donde se inician los tabs.

El problema es esta clase: `<div class="pull-right">`. Si la quito, mi formulario toma todo el espacio del `panel-primary` pero los tabs se pegan a la izquierda sobre el título.

Éste es mi código:

```css
/*Panel tabs*/
.panel-tabs {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  clear:both;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.panel-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.panel-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  line-height: .85;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-tabs > li.active > a,
.panel-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.panel-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .23);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title" style=" font-size: 12px;">Traslados Presupuestarios</h6>
      <!-- SI COLOCO ESTA CLASE EN EL DIV, TODO EL RESTO DEL FORMULARIO SE CORRE A LA IZQUIERDA -->
      <div class="pull-right">
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
          <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">I</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Número de Solicitud</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1" align="right">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Fecha</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1" align="right">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Disminuciones Bs.</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2" align="right">
            <label for="textArea" class="control-label">Concepto</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="textArea" placeholder="Email" style="font-size:11px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Nuevo</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Siguiente</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente? Si lo que quieres es que el formulario ocupe todo el ancho solo tienes que poner un `clear:both` en la etiqueta `form`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Investigando encontré la solución a mi problema, (la agrego como respuesta a mi pregunta). Nuevamente, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución rápida (dependiendo lo que quieras) consiste en poner a flotar a la izquierda (clase pull-left) el h6 que está al mismo nivel del contenedor de los tabs, y aplicarle la clase clearfix al elemento que los contiene.

El resto son ajustes mínimos de posición como hacer que los dos elementos tengan el mismo line-height y no utilizar el posicionamiento relativo para los tabs.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <h6 class="panel-title pull-left" style=" font-size: 12px;">Traslados Presupuestarios</h6>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <!-- Tabs -->
                <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">I</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ..... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

y el css

```
.panel-heading h6.panel-title {
  line-height: 36px;
}

.panel-tabs {
  position: static;
  bottom: auto;
  clear: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Tu opción me funciono, igual seguí investigando y la solución estaba en la clase del div al cual llama el boton tab

```html
<div class="container" id="divTablas" style="display: none">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top: -14px">
   <li class="active">
    <a href="#disminuir" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Disminuir</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
    <a href="#aumentar" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Aumentar</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="disminuir">
          ..
          ..
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="aumentar">
          ..
          ..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el div que se muestra para la primera pestaña del tab

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="disminuir">
```

Para el div de la segunda pestaña solo tuve que agregarle la clase "active" y me funciona perfectamente

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade active" id="aumentar">
```

De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Saludos